# Сортировка строк в таблице с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, сортировка

Есть такая таблица:

```
<tbody class="ui-sortable">         
       <tr data-item="id">
          <td>
              <span data-name="sort" data-value="34" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input  type="text" name="name" value="">
          </td>
       </tr>                    
       <tr data-item="id">
          <td>
              <span data-name="sort" data-value="36" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input  type="text" name="name" value="">
          </td>
       </tr>                    
       <tr data-item="id">
          <td>
              <span data-name="sort" data-value="33" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input  type="text" name="name" value="">
          </td>
       </tr>                    
       <tr data-item="id">
          <td>
              <span data-name="sort" data-value="35" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <input  type="text" name="name" value="">
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Нужно отсортировать строки по убыванию по атрибуту `data-value` который есть у span'a с атрибутом `data-name` который находится внутри строки, в первой ячейке.

Как это сделать?

*p.s. Плагины и проч. готовые решения - не интересны*

Comment: вы используете плагин [Sortable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable)?

Comment: извините, забыл уточнить что именно руками, без сторонних плагинов

Comment: что-то я просмотрел, оказывается jQuery тоже можно было использовать :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как jQuery возвращает коллекцию элементов, то сортировать можно сразу ее, а потом просто вставить отсортированные строки обратно в контейнер.

```js
$('.ui-sortable tr').sort(function(a, b) { // сортируем
  return +$(b).find('[data-name=sort]').attr('data-value') - +$(a).find('[data-name=sort]').attr('data-value');
})
.appendTo('.ui-sortable');// возвращаем в контейнер
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="ui-sortable">
    <tr data-item="id">
      <td>
        <span data-name="sort" data-value="34" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle">34</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item="id">
      <td>
        <span data-name="sort" data-value="36" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle">36</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item="id">
      <td>
        <span data-name="sort" data-value="33" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle">33</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item="id">
      <td>
        <span data-name="sort" data-value="35" class="dragger ui-sortable-handle">35</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать бесплатный плагин tablesorter
Документация с примерами: http://tablesorter.com/docs/
Ссылка на скачивание http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.zip

Comment: извините, забыл уточнить что именно руками, без сторонних плагинов

Answer (score 1):

Запилил так:

```
var sorting = [], sortNumber = function(a, b){return b - a};
listPropertiesTable.find('[data-name="sort"]').each(function(){
    sorting.push(Number($(this).data('value')));
});

sorting = sorting.sort(sortNumber);

for(var i in sorting){
    listPropertiesTable.find('[data-name="sort"][data-value="'+sorting[i]+'"]')
        .closest('tr')
        .appendTo('table > tbody');
}
```

Выглядит ужасно, но работает так как необходимо. Если есть способ более продуктивный, всегда рад комментариям)